# Update user counts in admin interface

Tags: users

I am working on a multi-user WordPress setup and have made it so a particular type of user can only add/edit users that they have authored. The code for this like this:

```
function isa_pre_user_query( $user_search ) {
if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) { 
    global $wpdb;

    $user_search->query_where = str_replace(
        'WHERE 1=1', 
        "WHERE 1=1 AND {$wpdb->users}.ID IN (
          SELECT {$wpdb->usermeta}.user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta 
          WHERE {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'
          AND {$wpdb->usermeta}.meta_value LIKE '%editor%' )", 
        $user_search->query_where
    );
}
}add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'isa_pre_user_query' );
```

This works well but the user counts displays incorrectly.

[image]
[image]

i renamed all roles as Administrator=>System User,Subscriber=>Salesman,Customer=>Stock Purchaser,Contributor=>Customer Relationship Officer,Editor=>Dealer.
By using above function i successfully listed dealers only to Customer Relationship Officer as cro can add only dealer. So how can i change user count and show only dealer count and all for dealer count. Please can anybody suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I created a hook for that and that hook is:

```
add_filter("views_users", 'custom_editor_counts', 10, 1);

function custom_editor_counts($views) {
    $view=$views;
    if ( current_user_can( 'contributor' ) ) {
        unset($views['all']);
        unset($views['administrator']);
        unset($views['subscriber']);
        unset($views['customer']);
        unset($views['contributor']);
        unset($views['shop_manager']);
        return $views;
    }else{
        $views=$view;
        return $views;
    }
}
```

This works for me.